# how to access extension html elements from chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, listener

I have connected web page with the chrome extension. Collecting response in background.js. Following is my code:

## manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "CIC Wallet",
  "description": "The CIC Wallet in your browser",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "Image/CI_logo-01.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": { "16": "Image/CI_logo-01.png",
    "48": "Image/CI_logo-01.png",
   "128": "Image/CI_logo-01.png" 
  },
  "background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1:5500/main.html"]
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "popup.js", "background.js"
    ],
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

## background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('from webpage');
    window.open("popup.html", "CIC Notification", "width=357,height=600,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no");
    document.getElementById("sendtrform").style.display="block";
});
```

## main.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function load(event){

  var createButton = document.getElementById('btn_buy_trust');
  createButton.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    var laserExtensionId = "myextID";
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(laserExtensionId, 'Hi from Webpage',
    function(response) {

    });
  });
});
```

main.js is the js file from my webpage, on button click, I am sending the message. In background.js, I am collecting the response and opens my extension HTML file in the separate window. Here in background.js, I am not able to access HTML elements from the popup.html file.
I am getting an error for this line:

```
document.getElementById("sendtrform").style.display="block";
```

Can somebody help me, how can I access HTML elements from background.js?

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page so accessing its DOM won't do you no good. Do it inside popup.js that you load in popup.html. See also [Modify a tab with an extension html file inside when opened from popup](//stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: You mean `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` in popup.js?

Comment: No, the listener stays in the background script.

Comment: But I want to do some functionality with the HTML elements just after getting a response from the listener.

Comment: Then do it inside the popup script.

Comment: sorry @wOxxOm but I am confused, popup.js is the file where my extension's complete logic is written. How I will get to know in popup.js whether I received the message in background.js or not. I am opening an extension window in a new tab using window.open(). But I directly want to open the form from extension (which is currently opened on button click) filled with the values sent from the webpage in background.js. So want to trigger button click from extension html just after I open extension using window.open().

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm for your valuable replies. I refer your given link, understand the problem and solved it.

Comment: See the answer I've linked in my first comment. It's how you can transfer the state/info from your background script to your popup.js.